# Pause Swift code execution while online data loads?

Tags: ios, mysql, swift

I am making a simple app for a church that retrieves a random name from a MySQL database of members and sets the "retrieve name" button text to the member name. It mostly works but the very first tap of the button does not change the button text, although the prints show that it is properly retrieving the name from the database. As I repeatedly tap, sometimes the text changes and sometimes it doesn't. I'm thinking that it may be because the data hasn't loaded yet and Swift is proceeding to the next piece of code too quickly. Is there a proper way to delay this until the data has loaded? Thank you!

Here is the app code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Grace Tabernacle Prayer App
//
//  Created by Nico Pampaloni on 1/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Pampaloni Code. All rights reserved.
//
// Simple app to retrieve a random name from a MySQL database and    display that name as the button text.


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // set URL of php script as NSURL
        let scriptUrl = "https://gtinternal.com/api/getname.php"
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: scriptUrl);
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        // use HTTP GET to retreive request data
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        // store the GET response and convert to a String
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

            let memberName = responseString as String

            print(responseString)

            // change Button text to retrieved string
            sender.setTitle(memberName, for: .normal)
        }

        task.resume()  
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the code inside of the task executes asynchronously as part of a closure block. This means that it is not running on the main thread. You then attempt to update your UI from the background thread, which will give unexpected results. Always put your UI code on the main thread. When you set the title on `sender` put that code in a block to execute on the main thread.

...

```Swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // change Button text to retrieved string
  sender.setTitle(memberName, for: .normal)
}
```

...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It worked. Now I just need to learn more about that concept and function call for future use. 
I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nico - if you're happy with the answer, you need to accept it and give credit to @faircloud ...  It also means that this question won't show up in the list of unanswered questions, meaning that other people who are trying to help won't waste time looking at something which is already resolved.